# How to simulate taps/swipes on android over other apps?

Tags: android, android-ndk, automation

I need to create an app which will simulate user input over other apps.
I have a server app running on another device on the same network which records inputs, and then streams that input to all devices on the network running the client. The clients will be run as root. The client app will NOT be the active app. I basically want to play 4 instances of a multiplayer game with only one device driving them.

**What is the best way to simulate these taps, long presses, swipes, etc on the clients?**

If anyone has any advice on the best methods for recording I would love this as well.

Comment: To be clear, I have an understanding of the different ways this can be done. I really want to know what the BEST way, to do this type of task. The user inputs are not simple x,y coordinate taps. They are long drags, swipes, multi-touch inputs, etc. I think I am just going to listen for all input events and grab the coordinates/types on the server, than then stream them to the clients. Using "shell input TYPE x y" is likely the easiest but complex long drags may be difficult. I really love some of the macro apps like repetitouch, hiro macro, etc. I would love to clone with server/client instead

Comment: What option have you resorted to ?

Comment: I've been doing this now for a few years since I posted this. The best way is in my oppinion writing scripts on a PC and sending commands over USB with adb shell input. Its possible to do from the phone if its rooted, but PC's are a better environment for scripting and making decisions than on the phone.